# cordova azure offline data sync not working on multiple records entry after closing the app

Tags: android, cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services

Tried to use the azure mobile app  for my cordova project but the problem is when i am offline and i enter the data, the data is stored locally and upon going online the data is synced to the database, but

while we enter a record offline, close the app then reopen the app and again add the record the latest record is overwritten to the local db and the earlier records are lost while syncing to the azure database.

```
syncContext = client.getSyncContext();

                // Define an overly simplified push handler that discards
                // local changes whenever there is an error or conflict.
                // Note that a real world push handler will have to take action according
                // to the nature of conflict.
                syncContext.pushHandler = {
                    onConflict: function (pushError) {
                        return pushError.cancelAndDiscard();
                    },
                    onError: function (pushError) {
                        return pushError.cancelAndDiscard();
                    }
                };

                return syncContext.initialize(store);
            });
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Thanks Aaron for coming out to help, but anyway got the solution just updated the cancel and proceed function to append and proceed and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways got the answer to the problem had to replace

```
pushError.cancelAndDiscard();
```

call to

```
pushError.appendAndDiscard();
```

and worked excellent as required for me